# xcuitest - unable to find elements in webview

Tags: ios, xcuitest

I'm trying to troubleshoot an identical issue with one of our ios apps that involves webview where xcuitest freezes and fails to find any element on devices/simulators with ios 13.3.

- Xcode version : 11.3
- macos : Catalina
- ios: 13.3

Since the source of this app cannot be disclosed, I created a sample app with google.com in its webview and could see the test freeze similar to the above problem. The `debugDescription` does not print the text fields, neither other elements from google's home page.

https://github.com/sabarishnarain/snarain-ios-webview

Appreciate any leads from anyone. I wish the answer to this will help me solve the original problem.

Comment: There is an open radar for this currently: http://www.openradar.me/7493918